# Kubernetes calico-node issue - running 0/1

Tags: docker, kubernetes, calico

Hi I have two virtual machine in a local server with ubuntu 20.04 and i want to build a small cluster for my microservices. I ran the following step to setup my cluster but I got issue with calico-nodes. They are running with 0/1/

master.domain.com

- ubuntu 20.04
- docker --version = Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
- kubectl version = Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.4", GitCommit:"e87da0bd6e03ec3fea7933c4b5263d151aafd07c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-02-18T16:12:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

worker.domain.com

- ubuntu 20.04
- docker --version = Docker version 20.10.2, build 20.10.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.2
- kubectl version = Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.4", GitCommit:"e87da0bd6e03ec3fea7933c4b5263d151aafd07c", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-02-18T16:12:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

**STEP-1**

In the **master.domain.com** virtual machine I run the following commands

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
```

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

```
curl https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml -O
kubectl apply -f calico.yaml
```

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP               NODE    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-7f4f5bf95d-gnll8   1/1     Running   0          38s     192.168.29.195   master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   calico-node-7zmtm                          1/1     Running   0          38s     195.251.3.255    master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-74ff55c5b-ltn9g                    1/1     Running   0          3m49s   192.168.29.193   master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-74ff55c5b-nkhzf                    1/1     Running   0          3m49s   192.168.29.194   master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-kubem                                 1/1     Running   0          4m6s    195.251.3.255    master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kubem                       1/1     Running   0          4m6s    195.251.3.255    master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kubem              1/1     Running   0          4m6s    195.251.3.255    master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-2cr2x                           1/1     Running   0          3m49s   195.251.3.255    master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kubem                       1/1     Running   0          4m6s    195.251.3.255    master   <none>           <none>
```

**STEP-2**
In the **worker.domain.com** virtual machine I run the following commands

```
sudo kubeadm join 195.251.3.255:6443 --token azuist.xxxxxxxxxxx  --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**STEP-3**
In the **master.domain.com** virtual machine I run the following commands

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP               NODE    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-7f4f5bf95d-gnll8   1/1     Running   0          6m37s   192.168.29.195   master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   calico-node-7zmtm                          0/1     Running   0          6m37s   195.251.3.255    master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   calico-node-wccnb                          0/1     Running   0          2m19s   195.251.3.230    worker   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-74ff55c5b-ltn9g                    1/1     Running   0          9m48s   192.168.29.193   master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-74ff55c5b-nkhzf                    1/1     Running   0          9m48s   192.168.29.194   master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-kubem                                 1/1     Running   0          10m     195.251.3.255    master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kubem                       1/1     Running   0          10m     195.251.3.255    master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kubem              1/1     Running   0          10m     195.251.3.255    master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-2cr2x                           1/1     Running   0          9m48s   195.251.3.255    master   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-kxw4m                           1/1     Running   0          2m19s   195.251.3.230    worker   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kubem                       1/1     Running   0          10m     195.251.3.255    master   <none>           <none>
```

```
kubectl logs -n kube-system calico-node-7zmtm
...
...
2021-06-20 17:10:25.064 [INFO][56] monitor-addresses/startup.go 774: Using autodetected IPv4 address on interface eth0: 195.251.3.255/24
2021-06-20 17:10:34.862 [INFO][53] felix/summary.go 100: Summarising 11 dataplane reconciliation loops over 1m3.5s: avg=4ms longest=13ms ()
```

```
kubectl logs -n kube-system calico-node-wccnb
...
...
2021-06-20 17:10:59.818 [INFO][55] felix/summary.go 100: Summarising 8 dataplane reconciliation loops over 1m3.6s: avg=3ms longest=13ms (resync-filter-v4,resync-nat-v4,resync-raw-v4)
2021-06-20 17:11:05.994 [INFO][51] monitor-addresses/startup.go 774: Using autodetected IPv4 address on interface br-9a88318dda68: 172.21.0.1/16
```

As you can see for both calico nodes I get 0/1 running, Why??

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, could you tell more about the setup you're having (network wise) and the exact steps that led you to this outcome? Have you followed the [kubeadm prerequisites](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/). I'd reckon the issue could be related to the IP addresses. Your master node according to CIDR notation should be reserved for the broadcast address in this particular subnet.

Answer (score 0):

Got totally the same issue.

- CentOS 8
- kubectl kubeadm kubelet v1.22.3
- docker-ce version 20.10.9

The only difference worth mention is that I have to comment line

> `- --port=0`

in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml` or otherwise `scheduler` declared as `unhealthy` in

> kubectl get componentstatuses

Kubernetes API is advertised on a public IP address.
Public IP address of control panel node is substituted with `42.42.42.42` in kubectl print-out;
Public IP address of worker node is substituted with 21.21.21.21
Public domain name (which is also a hostname on Control Panel node) is substituted with `public-domain.work`

```
>kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide

NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE   IP                NODE                  NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
calico-kube-controllers-5d995d45d6-rk9cq       1/1     Running   0             76m   192.168.231.193   public-domain.work         <none>           <none>
calico-node-qstxm                              0/1     Running   0             76m   42.42.42.42       public-domain.work         <none>           <none>
calico-node-zmz5s                              0/1     Running   0             75m   21.21.21.21       node1.public-domain.work   <none>           <none>
coredns-78fcd69978-5xsb2                       1/1     Running   0             81m   192.168.231.194   public-domain.work         <none>           <none>
coredns-78fcd69978-q29fn                       1/1     Running   0             81m   192.168.231.195   public-domain.work         <none>           <none>
etcd-public-domain.work                        1/1     Running   3             82m   42.42.42.42       public-domain.work         <none>           <none>
kube-apiserver-public-domain.work              1/1     Running   3             82m   42.42.42.42       public-domain.work         <none>           <none>
kube-controller-manager-public-domain.work     1/1     Running   2             82m   42.42.42.42       public-domain.work         <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-5kkks                               1/1     Running   0             81m   42.42.42.42       public-domain.work         <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-xsc66                               1/1     Running   0             75m   21.21.21.21       node1.public-domain.work   <none>           <none>
kube-scheduler-public-domain.work              1/1     Running   1 (78m ago)   78m   42.42.42.42       public-domain.work         <none>           <none>
```

```
>kubectl get nodes -o wide

NAME                       STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION   INTERNAL-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE          KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
public-domain.work         Ready    control-plane,master   4h56m   v1.22.3   42.42.42.42      <none>        CentOS Stream 8   4.18.0-348.el8.x86_64   docker://20.10.9
node1.public-domain.work   Ready    <none>                 4h50m   v1.22.3   21.21.21.21      <none>        CentOS Stream 8   4.18.0-348.el8.x86_64   docker://20.10.10
```

```
>kubectl logs -n kube-system calico-node-qstxm

2021-11-09 15:27:38.996 [INFO][86] felix/int_dataplane.go 1539: Received interface addresses update msg=&intdataplane.ifaceAddrsUpdate{Name:"eth1", Addrs:set.mapSet{}}
2021-11-09 15:27:38.996 [INFO][86] felix/hostip_mgr.go 85: Interface addrs changed. update=&intdataplane.ifaceAddrsUpdate{Name:"eth1", Addrs:set.mapSet{}}
2021-11-09 15:27:38.997 [INFO][86] felix/ipsets.go 130: Queueing IP set for creation family="inet" setID="this-host" setType="hash:ip"
2021-11-09 15:27:38.998 [INFO][86] felix/ipsets.go 785: Doing full IP set rewrite family="inet" numMembersInPendingReplace=7 setID="this-host"

2021-11-09 15:27:40.198 [INFO][86] felix/iface_monitor.go 201: Netlink address update. addr="here:is:some:ipv6:address:that:has:nothing:to:do:with:my:control:panel:server:public:ipv6" exists=true ifIndex=3 2021-11-09 15:27:40.198 [INFO][86] felix/int_dataplane.go 1071: Linux interface addrs changed. addrs=set.mapSet{"fe80::9132:a0df:82d8:e26c":set.empty{}} ifaceName="eth1"
2021-11-09 15:27:40.198 [INFO][86] felix/int_dataplane.go 1539: Received interface addresses update msg=&intdataplane.ifaceAddrsUpdate{Name:"eth1", Addrs:set.mapSet{"here:is:some:ipv6:address:that:has:nothing:to:do:with:my:control:panel:server:public:ipv6":set.empty{}}}
2021-11-09 15:27:40.199 [INFO][86] felix/hostip_mgr.go 85: Interface addrs changed. update=&intdataplane.ifaceAddrsUpdate{Name:"eth1", Addrs:set.mapSet{"here:is:some:ipv6:address:that:has:nothing:to:do:with:my:control:panel:server:public:ipv6":set.empty{}}}
2021-11-09 15:27:40.199 [INFO][86] felix/ipsets.go 130: Queueing IP set for creation family="inet" setID="this-host" setType="hash:ip"
2021-11-09 15:27:40.200 [INFO][86] felix/ipsets.go 785: Doing full IP set rewrite family="inet" numMembersInPendingReplace=7 setID="this-host"

2021-11-09 15:27:48.010 [INFO][81] monitor-addresses/startup.go 713: Using autodetected IPv4 address on interface eth0: 42.42.42.42/24
```

```
> kube-system calico-node-zmz5s

2021-11-09 15:25:56.669 [INFO][64] felix/int_dataplane.go 1071: Linux interface addrs changed. addrs=set.mapSet{} ifaceName="eth1"
2021-11-09 15:25:56.669 [INFO][64] felix/int_dataplane.go 1539: Received interface addresses update msg=&intdataplane.ifaceAddrsUpdate{Name:"eth1", Addrs:set.mapSet{}}
2021-11-09 15:25:56.669 [INFO][64] felix/hostip_mgr.go 85: Interface addrs changed. update=&intdataplane.ifaceAddrsUpdate{Name:"eth1", Addrs:set.mapSet{}}
2021-11-09 15:25:56.669 [INFO][64] felix/ipsets.go 130: Queueing IP set for creation family="inet" setID="this-host" setType="hash:ip"
2021-11-09 15:25:56.670 [INFO][64] felix/ipsets.go 785: Doing full IP set rewrite family="inet" numMembersInPendingReplace=7 setID="this-host"

2021-11-09 15:25:56.769 [INFO][64] felix/iface_monitor.go 201: Netlink address update. addr="here:is:some:ipv6:address:that:has:nothing:to:do:with:my:worknode:server:public:ipv6" exists=false ifIndex=3

2021-11-09 15:26:07.050 [INFO][64] felix/summary.go 100: Summarising 14 dataplane reconciliation loops over 1m1.7s: avg=5ms longest=11ms ()
2021-11-09 15:26:33.880 [INFO][59] monitor-addresses/startup.go 713: Using autodetected IPv4 address on interface eth0: 21.21.21.21/24
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30298071)

Answer (score 0):

Seemed that issue was in closed BGP port due to firewall.

This commands on master node solved it for me:

```
>firewall-cmd --add-port 179/tcp --zone=public --permanent

>firewall-cmd --reload
```